# Unknown Array in PHP Result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to show tags separated with comma fetched from certain section of my website. The PHP functions I've created are:

```
$fid = intval($fid);
$query = $db->query("
    SELECT p.message
    FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."posts p
    LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."threads t ON(t.firstpost=p.pid)
    WHERE p.fid = '{$fid}'
");
$audio_tags_bit = '';
while($p = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
    $audio_tags_bit .= $p['message'];
}

$keys = get_tags($audio_tags_bit);
foreach($keys as $key)
{
    $keys .= $key.', ';
}
$keys = substr($keys,0,strlen($keys)-2);


function get_tags($str)
{
    $keywords = array();
    $str=utf8_decode($str);

    //clean string from html/bbcode
    $str = html_entity_decode($str);
    $str = strip_tags($str);
    $str = preg_replace('#\[(.*?)\]#','',$str);

    //replace - with space
    $str = preg_replace('#-#',' ',$str);

    //string in lowcase
    $str = strtolower($str);



    //clean string //only a-zA-Z0-9 and spaces
    $str = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]#','',$str);



    //split by whitespace
    $splits = preg_split('#\s+#',$str);

    foreach($splits as $key)
    {

        $key=trim($key);
        if($key=="" || strlen($key) < 4 || is_numeric($key) || isset($forbidden[$key])) continue;
        if(!isset($keywords[$key]))
        {
            $keywords[$key] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $keywords[$key]++;
        }
    }
    //sort, reverse
    asort($keywords);
    $keywords = array_reverse($keywords);
    $tmpkeywords =  array_keys(array_slice($keywords,0,$max));
    $keywords = array();
    foreach($tmpkeywords as $key)
    {
        array_push($keywords,$key);
    }
    return $keywords;
}
```

But the result it shows is:

`Arrayquid, carum, finem, quasi, ille, sapiens, itaque, semper, constructio, interrete, vacabit, reges, verum, etiam, quemque, sibi, quae, dixisset, modo, aiat, neget, elit, hanc, adipiscing, consectetur, ipsum, dolor, amet, ergo, intuens, curem, lorem, absolvere, signum, debet, institutum, illud, vehementer, esse, vexat, immo, more, stoicorum, enim, ista, lenius, alio, genere, maxime, natura, vellet, erat, satis, nondum, autem, explanatum, aliquando, faciamus, redderet, sextus, peducaeus, fortasse, epicurus, quidem, reddes, ipse, censes, latino, paucis, haec, additis, requiras, quod, fore, igitur, inquit`

Notice the `Array` in the beginning of the result. Where it comes from? I want the result should be like:

`quid, carum, finem, quasi, ille, sapiens, itaque, semper, constructio, interrete, vacabit, reges, verum, etiam, quemque, sibi, quae, dixisset, modo, aiat, neget, elit, hanc, adipiscing, consectetur, ipsum, dolor, amet, ergo, intuens, curem, lorem, absolvere, signum, debet, institutum, illud, vehementer, esse, vexat, immo, more, stoicorum, enim, ista, lenius, alio, genere, maxime, natura, vellet, erat, satis, nondum, autem, explanatum, aliquando, faciamus, redderet, sextus, peducaeus, fortasse, epicurus, quidem, reddes, ipse, censes, latino, paucis, haec, additis, requiras, quod, fore, igitur, inquit`

i.e. `Array` should not be there. Please help

Comment: Either that property was an array that you used as a string, or you're looking at a `var_dump` that just says "Array" because that's the type of the thing you're dumping.

Comment: @m59 - but if it was a vardump it wouldn't be formatted that way most likely.

Comment: Is the "array" in the keywords list when you get to "asort"? Because you seem to be doing a lot of stuff down there that appears excessive/un-needed.

Comment: before the loop, but after you declare `$keywords = array();` can you post the `vardump()` results of `$keyword`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$keys = get_tags($audio_tags_bit);
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $keys .= $key.', ';
}
```

to this:

```
$keywords = get_tags($audio_tags_bit);
foreach ($keywords as $key) {
    $keys .= $key.', ';
}
```

You're actually assigning the same variable inside the `foreach` loop like the one you used for the fetched results